# ERR: obj are not valid as react child

Tags: javascript, arrays, json, reactjs

I am using create-react-app with websocketserver backend. I am getting the error "Objects are not valid as a React child (found: object with keys {id, status}). If you meant to render a collection of children, use an array instead."

my backend

```
          std::string out = "[{\"id\": \"" + Event->getID().asString() + "\",";
          if (auto stateEvent = dynamic_cast<const StateReport*>(Event.get()))
          {
            out += "\"State-Event\": \"";
            out += stateToString(stateEvent->getState());
            out += "\"}]";
          }
          else
            out += "\"Unknown event\": \"\"}]";

          out += "\n";

          objcomm::Data resp;
          resp._data = (const std::uint8_t*)out.c_str();
```

react code

```
componentDidMount() {
    client.onmessage = (message) => {
      var data = message.data;
      this.setState({dataFromServer: data});
      console.log(message.data);
    };
  }

  render() {
    if(!this.state.dataFromServer){
      return "loading"
    }
    else if(this.state.dataFromServer && this.state.dataFromServer.length >0){
      return(
        this.state.dataFromServer.map(data => (
          {data}
        ))
      );
    }
  }
```

console log of message.data

```
  [{"id": "1.2","State-Event" : "Running"}]
```

I wanted to access something like
this.state.datafromServer.map(data => {data.id})
but when i do this i get datafromServer.map is not a func

what am i doing wrong.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Most likely, during the first execution of `render()` the value of **`this.state.dataFromServer`** will still be `undefined`, which explains the *"datafromServer.map is not a function"* error.

During the next `render()` execution it should have been set (as a result of the API having been called), and then you can use it.

This is a very common situation. See below for an example of how to deal with it:

```
render() {
  if (!this.state.dataFromServer)
    return <p>Loading...</p>;

  return this.state.dataFromServer.map(item => this.createElement(item));
}
```

The `this.createElement` is just an example here, it is up to you to either implement it, or to do something else with each `item`. A very simple (starter) implementation could be:

```
createElement = (item) => <p>id: {item.id}</p>
```

Comment: ah yes may be ! let me give a try. i forgot that i had to check if its exists.

Comment: no it didnt help. i still have the error.

Comment: In your updated code, the function inside the `map` call returns `{data}` which is a javascript object. It should return a JSX element (e.g. `<p>`, `<span>`, `<div>`) as I did in my example code.

Comment: yes i tried and i did a debug as well in console to see what value am i getting in this.state.dataFromServer and i get this. this.state.dataFromServer
"[{\"id\": \"1.2\",\"State-Event\": \"Running\"}]\n"

Comment: its wierd as i am not understanding from where this double quotes coming infront of square brackets. and due to this it throws an error: this.state.dataFromServer is not a map function

Comment: i think data = JSON.parse(message.data) is missing in my case

Comment: It looks like your data may be double encoded. Your backend creates a string containing JSON, which is then encoded by the backend framework *once more* as JSON. Then after doing JSON.parse() in the frontend, you end up with still a string containing JSON. You could run JSON.parse() a second time to get the data out of it, but really the most proper solution would be to construct an **object** in the backend containing the data as actual data properties, instead of creating a string that mimics such an object.